# Glassfish log in NetBeans: Domain Pinged

Tags: netbeans, glassfish, ping

Sometimes I get this message in the Glassfish log window of NetBeans:

```
Domain Pinged: stable.glassfish.org
```

Anybody has an idea of what it means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message is generated by the update Tool of GlassFish:

http://blogs.oracle.com/alexismp/entry/let_glassfish_update_itself_v3